# sqlite3 - how to update a row by multiple SET and WHERE variables

Tags: sqlite, python-3.5

I tried to update a row by the following expression in SQlite3 by using mutiple variables:

```
    sql = "UPDATE table SET column1 = ?, column2 = ?, column3 = ? WHERE field1 = ? AND field2 = ? AND field3 = ?";

    parameters = (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6)

    cursor.execute(sql, parameters)
```

But I got the following error:

```
    (<class 'sqlite3.ProgrammingError'>, ProgrammingError('Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 6 supplied.',)
```

How can I realize that update?

best regards

Comment: Sure that's the exact query you're trying to execute?

Comment: That query is not valid SQL. Show that actual code you're using.